About linear equation
What is the geometrically meaning of subtracting one linear equation from another I mean if I have two linear equations 2x + 5y = 5 and another is 3x + 2y = 10 then if I multiply each by some number then eliminate x terms and then find y put it into equation to find the value of x and y but when i subtract one equation from another or eliminate x what is the meaning of performing this operation geometrically?

Why is this receiving close votes and down-votes? Luka is not asking us to solve his problem. He has indicated that he knows how to solve this system of equations, but doesn't understand why the operations work.

Geometry isn't the way to think about this. If I have two equations that I want to solve simultaneously, say $$\begin{align}
2x+5y&=5\\
3x+2y&=10
\end{align}$$
the rules of multiplying by constants and adding or subtracting them are best understood by arithmetic.
Suppose I multiply the equation $2x+5y=5$ by $3$. Why does that work? We know that $$3\times 5=15$$ and that $$2x+5y=5$$. Therefore, $$3(2x+5y)=3(5)\implies 6x+15y=15$$
Geometrically, the line defined by the set of points that satisfy $$6x+15y=15$$ is the same line as the set of points that satisfy $$2x+5y=5$$
That is the point of the operation. All solutions of the original equation are still solutions when we multiply both sides by $3$.
Likewise, if we multiply $$3x+2y=10$$ by $2$, we don't change the solution set of the equation because we are multiplying both sides of the equation. In other words, since the sum on the left equals $10$, twice the sum equals $20$. Now we have the set of equations $$\begin{align}
6x+15y&=15\\
6x+4y&=20
\end{align}$$ and any solution of the first two equations is the same solution of this set of equations.
We now can use subtraction to eliminate the $x$ variable. Why does that work?
Suppose I subtract $20$ from both sides of the first equation. Since both sides of the equation are equal, subtracting or adding any value to both sides of the equation doesn't change anything. But subtracting $20$ is the same as subtracting $$6x+4y$$ because $$6x+4y=20$$
Therefore, we get $$10y=-5$$ which allows us to solve for $y$ and then for $x$.
